# How to get Max Salhike month but if max Salhike is same for two month then give lower number month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

**I am trying this:**

```
file.loc[((file['salhike'].max()) & (file['month'].min())), ["empid",'month','salhike'] ]
```

Comment: I mean this should give output: Month = 3 and Salhike = 87

Comment: Oh please do not post pictures

Comment: I am sorry, I was not able to add data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
Yourdf = df.sort_values(['saihike','month'],ascending=[False,True]).head(1)
```

Comment: Yes...Thanks. But, if I have 10 employees  like this then how I will use this code because I have to use GROUPBY first.

Comment: @subodhagrawal `Yourdf = df.sort_values(['saihike','month'],ascending=[False,True]).drop_duplicates(['empid'])
`